# Umbraco multilingual how to?

Tags: umbraco

There are 100 forum posts on this but none of them seem to work...

I would like a multilingual site like this:

- http: //mysite.com/en
- http: //mysite.com/fr

I have set up nodes like this:

- mysite.com (type: "language redirector")
- --- en (type: "home page")
- --- fr (type: "home page")

The top-level "language redirector" node uses some ASP.NET code to redirect to either /en or /fr depending on HTTP headers. Under "manage hostnames" there are no mappings.

Node /fr under "manage hostnames" has an entry like "fr.domain.com" pointing to French.

When I visit http: //mysite.com/fr and use Dictionary.DictionaryItem, the English value is returned, so it seems not to work.

I've tried useDomainPrefixes to both true and false, neither seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
- Brian

Comment: Why have an entry `fr.domain.com` if what you want is `mysite.com/fr` ?

Comment: Marapet - I've tried both style and neither seems to work. I read they can be fake domains, or should I use something like localhost/fr or 127.0.0.1:58447/fr for it to work?

Comment: Did you created the languages in 'Settings'-section and added them to the correct homepage?

Comment: If you have find the solution of you problem please share it.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Umbraco? If so, you are going about this the wrong way as you do not need a language redirector. This can be handled by the cultures option on a content node.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a snippet of the code/logic you are using for handling the Language redirection?

It sounds like it could potentially be down to your use of HTTP Headers for redirecting request to the correct site.

One reason that I could think of why you are getting the English version as opposed to the French version, could be down to your 'local' HTTP Headers (ie. If your redirect logic is using the following HTTP Header 'ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' and your local browser is set to English then you will always get the english site, does that make sense???).

Regards

Craig